# Any ideas how to change image to a https format in Firebase?

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native

I'm trying to make a react native competition app where the user can create new competitions and show them in the app. But the image upload saves as a file instead of an HTTPS link. Any ideas on how to fix it?

```
file:///var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/141B483E-F907-4043-A0FB-6D9C992E4BEC/Library/Caches/ExponentExperienceData/%2540anonymous%252FFunkySocky-0e5e9e8b-1ad4-4ea3-994f-97cd60981d53/ImagePicker/611ED925-EC36-4D2A-B485-52A0E482BF44.jpg
```

Comment: https is a protocol, not a file format

Answer (score 0):

As you do not provide much detail, I will answer in two parts.

First part is an explanation of what you are probably missing in your code. What you have between your hands is a URI to your local file. What you need to do now is convert that file into a blob and make a PUT request to Firebase Storage to upload it. Here is a function that can do that for you.

```js
async function uploadImageAsync(uri) {
  // Why are we using XMLHttpRequest? See:
  // https://github.com/expo/expo/issues/2402#issuecomment-443726662
  const blob = await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.onload = function () {
      resolve(xhr.response);
    };
    xhr.onerror = function (e) {
      console.log(e);
      reject(new TypeError("Network request failed"));
    };
    xhr.responseType = "blob";
    xhr.open("GET", uri, true);
    xhr.send(null);
  });

  const fileRef = ref(getStorage(), uuid.v4());
  const result = await uploadBytes(fileRef, blob);

  // We're done with the blob, close and release it
  blob.close();

  return await getDownloadURL(fileRef); // This will return the URL you are referring to.
}
```

Source: https://github.com/expo/examples/blob/master/with-firebase-storage-upload/App.js

Second part is a working example for uploading images to Firebase in React Native if you are **not using Expo** and have access to `rnfirebase`:

```js
import React, { useEffect } from 'react';
import { View, Button } from 'react-native';

import { utils } from '@react-native-firebase/app';
import storage from '@react-native-firebase/storage';

function App() {
  // create bucket storage reference to not yet existing image
  const reference = storage().ref('black-t-shirt-sm.png');

  return (
    <View>
      <Button
        onPress={async () => {
          // path to existing file on filesystem
          const pathToFile = `${utils.FilePath.PICTURES_DIRECTORY}/black-t-shirt-sm.png`;
          // uploads file
          await reference.putFile(pathToFile);
        }}
      />
    </View>
  );
}
```

Source: https://rnfirebase.io/storage/usage#upload-a-file